# Shortcut to launch an activity

Tags: android, permissions, android-intent

I have an app that create a shortcut in the following way:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, MYWEBVIEW.class);
String fileHtml = trovaHtml(path);
shortcutIntent.putExtra("appToLaunch", appId);
shortcutIntent.putExtra("fileHtml", fileHtml);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, dirAppName);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
this.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

I know that this code is deprecated but let's forget about it.......

MYWEBVIEW is not the main activity of my app, is a webview that open an offline html page, and the path to this html file is inside the extra value "fileHtml".

When i click on the shortcut i get this error:

> 08-08 14:15:37.907: ERROR/Launcher(165): Launcher does not have the permission to launch Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=market.finestraprincipale/.MyAppActivity bnds=[3,217][77,296] (has extras) }. Make sure to create a MAIN intent-filter for the corresponding activity or use the exported attribute for this activity. tag=ShortcutInfo(title=myFile) intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=market.finestraprincipale/.MYWEBVIEW bnds=[3,217][77,296] (has extras) }
>
> 08-08 14:15:37.907: ERROR/Launcher(165): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=market.finestraprincipale/.MYWEBVIEW bnds=[3,217][77,296] (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{405875c8 165:com.android.launcher/10026} (pid=165, uid=10026) requires null

How can I fix these errors? Is there a way to create two instances of the same app?

For example I'm inside my app, I create a shortcut, I press home button so the application goes to background and when I click on the shortcut I start MYWEBVIEW activity but inside a new instance of my app.....so basically I can have more webviews opened at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have the following permission in your `manifest.xml`?

```xml
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Also see that the activity you are trying to launch has the following intent filter defined:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yes i have, i don't get the error creating the shortcut, i get it when i click on the shortcut......probably cause it's calling an activity that is not the main one......a t least i suppose..

Comment: Try adding ``permission.INTERNET``. It might be that the shortcut is trying to launch the browser (since you're trying to open a URL). Are you sub-classing the ``WebViewClient`` class as is suggested [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)?

Comment: Yes i'm doing both....If i surf through my app from the main activity to MYWEBVIEW, everything works fine, it opens the right html page.....but if i tried to open it straigh from the shortcut i get that error......can a shortcut open an activity that is not the main one? Cause if i change the target of the shortcut to the main activity of my app it works :( but i need to go straight to another one

Comment: Ok I realize I'm guessing at this point, which is not ideal, but no one else seems to be jumping on this. Can you try adding an <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /></intent-filter> to your ``MYWEBVIEW`` activity?

Comment: Great! I'll update my answer so that it reflect *a* solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add
       action 
    within your MYWEBVIEW activity in the manifest file.I try this and it working.